# How to say "A Person's Strength"

Tags: grammar

Is there a good translation for "strengths" in Chinese? I am trying to say strengths as in 'We should try to improve our strengths, not our weaknesses'. 
I know that 强项 is one phrase that has a similar meaning - is this used? Or is there a better way to translate "strengths and weaknesses"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

强项 can definitely be used for strengths - where weaknesses would be 弱项.

There is also:

优点和缺点

yōudiǎn hé quēdiǎn

merits and demerits; virtues and defects; strong and weak point

Also: 长处和短处

See which you like...

Comment: Also suggest 优势和不足